# Java 6 applications are prevented from being deployed to Google App Engine from any version of the SDK

Tags: java, google-app-engine, java-6

When i tried to deploy the Java 6 application in App engine. I got error like

```
Java 6 applications are prevented from being deployed to Google App Engine from any    
version of the SDK, including older ones. If you need to continue to deploy Java 6 
applications for compatibility reasons, you can request that your application be 
whitelisted for Java 6 deployment by visiting link.
```

Then i changed java version 1.7 in project settings. Even after, app engine deployment throw same error.

How to fix this issue.

Comment: Have you change to Java JDK7 (not JRE) in both "Java Build Path" and "Java Compiler" of project properties?

Comment: Yes, I changed the both Build Path and Java Compiler.

Comment: As a tip, I faced alike but re-deployment problem; But today I succeeded to deploy on gae by using eclipse kepler 4.3 which has jdk compliance settings as 1.7 and appengine-api-sdk-1.8.5 which comes as default one with the eclipse kepler 4.3 gwt 2.5 plugin; I hope that helps a bit...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally fix this issue by installing Eclipse 4.3 `Kepler` and App Engine SDK 1.9.2.

**Install Latest Eclipse 4.3**

https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

**Install Latest Google Eclipse Plugin**

https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/getting_started

Answer (score 0):

Create a new small Java 7 project that deploys and runs successfully.  Copy your existing application content into the new project.  Rename the old project to use it as an archive.  Rename the new project to use the original project name and application id.

Comment: Sorry. This does not hep.

Comment: Are you unable to deploy any AppEngine projects at all, or is the problem only with the formerly Java 6 based project?  How about trying the guestbook tutorial?

Comment: I create new application in the App Engine and try to upload sample `guestbook` application with new application id, it `DOES NOT WORK`. I uses App Engine SDK 1.7.3 version. Will that be problem?

Comment: You've probably just identified the cause of the problem.  SDK 1.7.3 is too old for the AppEngine software in Google's cloud.  It's now on 1.9.2.  In Eclipse, try selecting Help -> Check for Updates. or if that does not work try a fresh SDK install by following [Google Plugin for Eclipse Quick Start](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/getting_started)

Comment: Thanks, i will try and let you know. Moreover i have Google Eclipse Plugin 4.2, NOT 4.3. Do i need to update eclipse plugin too?

Comment: Yes you should update your Eclipse plugin.  For example Debian Stable users get Eclipse 3.8, which is almost identical to Eclipse 4.2, and all these Eclipse versions currently require AppEngine SDK 1.9.2.

Comment: Thank you very much. Installing Latest Eclipse 4.3 `Kepler` and App Engine SDK 1.9.2 solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Eclipse, check at Preferences>Java>Compiler. The JDK Compliance is (on my laptop) not updated to the version 1.7