# Why am I getting a 400 error, as I try to deploy my app from netbeans?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, netbeans

While trying to deploy my `google app engine` application from netbeans I get the following error :

```
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=programworks&version=1&
400 Bad Request
Java 6 applications are prevented from being deployed to Google App Engine from any version of the SDK, including older ones. If you need to continue to deploy Java 6 applications for compatibility reasons, you can request that your application be whitelisted for Java 6 deployment by visiting http://goo.gl/ycffXq.

Unable to update app: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=programworks&version=1&
400 Bad Request
Java 6 applications are prevented from being deployed to Google App Engine from any version of the SDK, including older ones. If you need to continue to deploy Java 6 applications for compatibility reasons, you can request that your application be whitelisted for Java 6 deployment by visiting http://goo.gl/ycffXq.
```

What is this error all about ? I am using `java 7` as my library.

Comment: Check in the project properties, category sources, bottom of the page there is a Source/Binary Format selector.  Is that one set to 1.7 as well?

Comment: @fvu Getting the same error after setting it.

Comment: @fvu I was able to deploy earlier but am having the problem now.

Comment: what version of the google app engine sdk are you using?

Comment: @fvu `appengine java sdk 1.6.6`

Comment: Then head over to the [download page](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/downloads/list) and get something fresher, 1.9.0 is the current version.  The [release notes page](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkForJavaReleaseNotes) has some more info about the deprecation of Java 6 apps.

Comment: @fvu does it have anything to do with jdk version ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new small Java 7 project that deploys and runs successfully. Copy your existing application content into the new project. Rename the old project to use it as an archive. Rename the new project to use the original project name and application id. (originally [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22300795/java-6-applications-are-prevented-from-being-deployed-to-google-app-engine-from/22305922#22305922) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22300795/java-6-applications-are-prevented-from-being-deployed-to-google-app-engine-from)).